# Difference between using native keyword in

Tags: java, android

Difference between using native keyword in

```
public static native void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException
```

and

```
public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos) throws InterruptedException
```

Comment: As in any other case - the first method is `native`, and is provided by some non-java library... What are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `native` keyword indicates that the method is implemented in native code. (C / C++) using JNI. Since you also tagged android, here is some documentation for further clarification. [JNI Tips - Android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep(long) is native because it is mapped directly onto the underlying operating system's thread management (ie. on Windows it behaves differently than on Linux or Solaris or any other system). Thread.sleep(long, int) is not native, because it does some internal logic in Java and then calls Thread.sleep(long). See the source code for details.

Source: http://www.coderanch.com/mobile/t/472436/threads/java/Sleep-method-Native?foo=a